# Sharepoint 2010 Online to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

Can some one please explain me or point me to a nice article whats the main difference between Sharepoint 2010 Online and O365 and how can we upgrade from Sharepoint 2010 online to O365

Answer (score 0):

Richard Harbridge has created a good overview/summary of that. http://www.rharbridge.com/?page_id=966